# Error displaying data from mysql database using $smarty

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

can someone please guide me whats wrong in this part sometimes its fetching all data from database, sometime only first row and sometimes nothing..any help or alternate method will be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

**my-module/mymodule.php**:

```html
public function hookHome($params)
 {
 
  $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/style.css', 'all');
 
  $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/main.js', 'all');
  
  if (!$this->isCached('my-module.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
  {
   $infos = $this->getInfos($this->context->language->id, $this->context->shop->id);
   $this->context->smarty->assign(array('infos' => $infos, 'nbblocks' => count($infos)));
  }
 
  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'my-module.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
 }
 
 public function getInfos($id_lang, $id_shop)
 {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'table1` ';
 
  return Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
 }
```

and here is my my-module/mymodule.tmp:

```html
<div class="my-class">
 <ul class="my-class-child">
 
{if $infos|@count > 0} 
 
    {foreach from=$infos item=info}
 
        <li>
  <p>{$info.id}</p>
   <div class="cd-author">
    <img src='{$info.image}' alt="my-img">
    <ul class="csd">
     <li>{$info.value1}</li>
     <li>{$info.value2}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </li>
     {/foreach}
{/if}
   </ul>
 
</div>
```

here is my table structure

**table 1**:

```
--------------------------------------
id   |  image   |  value1 |  value2
--------------------------------------
1    |  x.jpg   |  abc    |   xyz
--------------------------------------
2    |  x.jpg   |  abc    |   xyz
--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

got this solved thanks to smarty official page:
modify as follows

php file :

```html
if (!$this->isCached('my-module.tpl', $this->getCacheId()))
  {
   $infos = $this->getInfos($this->context->language->id, $this->context->shop->id);
   $this->context->smarty->assign(array('infos' => $infos, 'nbblocks' => count($infos)));
  }
```

to this

```html
 global $smarty; 
 
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'blocktesti` ';

  $sql1= Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
  $smarty->assign('contacts', $sql1);
```

tmp file from this

```html
{if $infos|@count > 0} 
 
    {foreach from=$infos item=info}
 
        <li>
  <p>{$info.id}</p>
   <div class="cd-author">
    <img src='{$info.image}' alt="my-img">
    <ul class="csd">
     <li>{$info.value1}</li>
     <li>{$info.value2}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </li>
     {/foreach}
{/if}
```

to this

```html
{section name=co loop=$contacts}
    <li>
  <p>{$contacts[co].id}</p>
   <div class="cd-author">
    <img src='{$contacts[co].image}' alt="Author image">
    <ul class="cd-author-info">
     <li>{$contacts[co].value1}</li>
     <li>{$contacts[co].value2}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>
{sectionelse}
  <h3>No Data found</h3>
{/section}
```